# Filtering python dict by abs minimal value, returning many

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to filter a python dictionary to include only the minimum absolute values, returning a new dict with all key,value pairs which have the same `min(abs())` match. I've coded up the following solution:

```
def return_closest_vals(dc):
    # min_val = dc[min(dc, key=dc.get)]

    min_val = 1e3
    keys_matching_min_val = {}
    for d, v in dc.items():
        if abs(v) < min_val:
            min_val = abs(v)
            keys_matching_min_val = {d:v} # updating min_val means keys matchin are outdated. Reset with new val
        elif abs(v) == min_val:
            keys_matching_min_val[d] = v

    return keys_matching_min_val

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_dict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":-1, "d":2, "e":1}
    expected_outcome = {"a":1, "c":-1, "e":1}
    print(return_closest_vals(test_dict))
```

but I don't think it's very elegant. Is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: There is a bug in that `min_val` is not the absolute value so it would fail the second if condition. Set `"a": -1` to see.

Comment: Yes I see the bug now, thanks! Updated the original question. There's still no nicer way to do this?

Comment: I don't see an alternative way of doing this that gets the result in one pass. You can make it simpler if you are willing to loop over the dictionary twice. First using `min` and second using dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that generates the correct output however it loops over the provided dictionary twice. If one pass is your requirement then your original solution is best.

```py
def return_closest_vals(dc):
    if not dc: return {}

    min_val = min(abs(v) for v in dc.values())
    return {k:v for k,v in dc.items() if abs(v) == min_val}
```